# Get checkmark values of uitableview after clicking a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to get the values of multiple selection of tableview on clicking a button.I checked lot of stackoverflow questions but unable to get the answer. I know this is already achieved by many people so i request someone to guide me about getting the values from tableview. I am able to select mulitple values from tableview.I am able to see checkmark.

Below is my code

```
.h file
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *specTableView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arForTable;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *arForIPs;//to capture ids
- (IBAction)btnActionToGetValues:(id)sender;

.m file

- (void)viewDidLoad {
 self.arForTable=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"value1",@"value2",@"value3",@"value4", nil];
    self.arForIPs=[NSMutableArray array];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.arForTable count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    if([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]){
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    } else {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]){
        [self.arForIPs removeObject:indexPath];
    } else {
        [self.arForIPs addObject:indexPath];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];

}

//button action for getting values
- (IBAction)btnActionToGetValues:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"ids %@",arForIPs);
}
```

I am getting this output

> ids (
>       " {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
>       " {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}" )

My expected output is

> ids (
>       "Value1",
>       "Value2" )

If any one has already worked on this please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
-  (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
if([self.arForIPs containsObject:[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
    [self.arForIPs removeObject:[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
} else {
    [self.arForIPs addObject:[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
[tableView reloadData];

}
```

on your `CellforRowatIndexpath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if([self.arForIPs containsObject:[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]){
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
} else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
cell.textLabel.text=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

**output you can get**

```
//button action for getting values
- (IBAction)btnActionToGetValues:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"ids %@",arForIPs);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can create one new array,example:

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [NSMutableArray array];


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]){
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    [arr addObject:self.arForTable[indexPath.row]];
} else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [arr removeObject:self.arForTable[indexPath.row]];
}
cell.textLabel.text=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (IBAction)btnActionToGetValues:(id)sender {
NSLog(@"ids %@",arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, i used anbu.karthik solution.Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in your log is the `indexPath` value of your cells. The `length` value is how many items are in the path (2) and the `path` value is showing the row and section of the cell the user tapped.

If you will use the index path value to get a reference to the cell; you can ask the cell if it has a checkmark turned on. You are also holding the values in your `arForTable` array. So, you use the index path from the `tableView` to ask the `arForTable` array for the value. I might write the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSString *valueFromArray = [[self arForTable] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]; 

if([self.arForIPs containsObject:valueFromArray]){
    [self.arForIPs removeObject:valueFromArray];
} else {
      [self.arForIPs addObject:valueFromArray];
}
[tableView reloadData];

}
```

Of course, this will cause your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to break. So you will need to update that as well. Perhaps replace this:

```
 if([self.arForIPs containsObject:indexPath]){
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
} else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
cell.textLabel.text=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

with something like:

```
NSString *valueString = [[self arForTable] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
if([self.arForIPs containsObject:valueString]){
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
} else {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
}
cell.textLabel.text=valueString;
```

Often in a `tableView` you will find that the array (`arForTable`) holds the data and since the `index` property of the array matches the `row` property of the tableView we can use that match to query the array for the data that corresponds to the tableView row that we are displaying.

Comment: Thanks for your response Walter, I used anbu.karthik solution its working fine.